# I want to test my Swift app on Azure Pipelines with Appium

Tags: swift, xcode, azure-pipelines, appium, webdriver-io

Webdriver.io configuration values

```
platformName: 'iOS',
maxInstances: 5,
automationName: 'XCUITest',
deviceName: 'iPhone 11',
platformVersion: '14.5',
app: path.resolve(`. /{app}.zip`),
```

I was able to communicate with the simulator.

```
[DevCon Factory] Successfully requested the connection for ~
```

Driver also started.

```
[WebDriverAgent] Launching WebDriverAgent on the device
```

However, the connection cannot be made and time is expired

```
[WD Proxy] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100
```

What is the cause?

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to test my Swift app on Azure Pipelines with Appium

According to the document [Decide how you will deploy and test your app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/continuous-test-selenium?view=azure-devops#decide-how-you-will-deploy-and-test-your-app):

> You can deploy and test your app using either the Microsoft-hosted
> agent in Azure, or a self-hosted agent that you install on the target
> servers.
>
> - When using the Microsoft-hosted agent, you should use the Selenium web drivers that are pre-installed on the Windows agents (agents
>   named Hosted VS 20xx) because they are compatible with the browser
>   versions installed on the Microsoft-hosted agent images. The paths to
>   the folders containing these drivers can be obtained from the
>   environment variables named IEWebDriver (Internet Explorer),
>   ChromeWebDriver (Google Chrome), and GeckoWebDriver (Firefox). **The
>
>   drivers are not pre-installed on other agents such as Linux, Ubuntu,
>
>   and macOS agents. Also see UI testing considerations**.

So, please try to use the use the Selenium web drivers that are pre-installed on the Windows agents (agents named Hosted VS 20xx).